# How to set some data object to JFace TableViewer row

Tags: java, swt, jface

Currently, I rework on my code , because I want to use MVC and JFace. Native SWT provides the possibility to add some Objects to a SWT-TableItem by using the function .setData(..):

```
TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE, 1);
item.setData(someObject)
```

Is there a chance to do this in my new created Label- or ContentProviders?

Comment: I think this is best avoided  as the TableViewer may create new table items when you do things like refreshing the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TableViewer` (and other viewers) uses the `item.setData(object)` method itself to associate your data model object with the item. Setting the data value to something else will break the viewer.

Also the viewer does not guarantee to use the same item for a particular row for the life time of the table. Operations such as `refresh` may use new table items.